# Iterate run inscript command line tool over all html files in subfolders

Tags: loops, zsh, subdirectory

I would like to convert a large number of html files to txt files. I have downloaded the inscript command line tool from github but I am struggling to apply it to all html files which are located in subdirectories and then save these files as text files in the same directory where the html files are located.

I have tried:

`for f in ./ do inscript.py -o test.txt done`

Comment: What does `inscript.py` use for input? All the HTML files in the current working directory?

Comment: Inscript.py uses one html file as input and produces one txt file as output.

Comment: Do you want a separate output file for each input file?

Comment: Yes, I'd like a separate output for each file. It can have the same name as the input or some incrementing name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for d in ./**/*/; do
  pushd "$d"
  for f in *.html(N); do
    out=test-${f%.html}.txt
    inscript.py -o "$out" "$f"
  done
  popd
done
```

The pattern `.**/*/` will recursively match the current directory and all its subdirectories. `pushd` will change to a directory, but remember the current working directory. `inscript.py` does its thing, then `popd` returns to the original working directory so that the next value of `d` continues to be a valid
relative directory.

Changing the working directory isn't strictly necessary; it just simplifies the file paths involved, because you focus on the name of the file and ignore the rest of the path.

Comment: Unfortunately, the script starts running but gets stuck without an error message.

Comment: Based on your update, perhaps replace `inscript.py -o test.txt` with `for f in ./*.html; do inscript.py -o "test-${f%.html}.txt" "$f"; done`?

Comment: I tried this and it tells me that "zsh: no matches found: ./*.html" probably because all the html files are in subdirectories. So I re-ran ```for f in ./**/*; do inscript.py -o "test-${f%.html}.txt" "$f"; done``` and received the error message: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test-./folder/file.txt'

Comment: Use `setopt NULL_GLOB` so that `./*.html` simply produces 0 results rather than raising an error.

Comment: There's also a glob qualifier that lets you turn `NULL_GLOB` on just for a single pattern: `for f in ./*.html(N)`; I've included this in the answer, though if you need this for `./**/*/` as well then you might want to set the option rather than qualifying each glob individually.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/inscript.py", line 53, in <module>
    with open(args.output, 'w') as open_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test-./file.txt'

The way I read this error is that inscript tries to take file.txt as an input when it should take it as an output. Inscript.py syntax requires: inscript.py inputfile -o outputfile.txt.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary `./` from the pattern, so the value of `out` should now be a simple file name, not a path.